# ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, xcode6

I'm very very new to C and C++ programming, and have very little experience in Software Programming (my background is Web Based) But I'm trying to experiment with C / C++ and Xcode... So I've found this code (and many similar variations online):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("Test");
    return 0;
}
```

Yet when I come to compile it in Xcode I get the following error:

```
> duplicate symbol _main in:
>     /Users/thomas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-etqojvxbxhxjqeggdzkbfufvbeza/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/first.o
>     /Users/thomas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-etqojvxbxhxjqeggdzkbfufvbeza/Build/Intermediates/test.build/Debug/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
> ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Maybe Xcode is the wrong thing for me to be using as a newbie? If anyone could recommend a better compiler, that would be great too!

Comment: I'm not into Macs so I can't help more but it's something wrong with your environment, not the code. You should try with GCC.

Comment: By chance, is there a `main` function in both `main.c` and `first.c`? Or how are you compiling them? You seem to be linking two object files together.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you create a new project in Xcode, it automatically gives you a starting file with `main()` in it. If you created a new file, such as `first.c`, and then pasted your test code into it, you'll be defining `main()` twice, and getting that error.

You need to either delete the file (such as `main.c`, or `main.m`) that Xcode provides in your new project, or cut and paste your sample code into that file, instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had created another .c file and Xcode was seeing this as another main file and hence created the error -> **duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64**

Select the second .c file -> Show the File Inspector -> and remove the target membership on the second .c file in your project to get rid of this error.

[image]

@Thomas Fearn - you will need to remove the target membership on the **first.c** file.

Comment: This works, but it is commonly not the correct approach. Please don't work against the tool. -- A project has just one `main()`. If you want another application, create a new project.

Comment: Though for the organization of code and rather than having a huge monolithic page of code, what do you suggest if your trying to have a struct in another file @the busybee?

Comment: Please post this as a question. From the single sentence I don't understand exactly what you like to know. -- You can have as many files in a project as you see fit. But only one `main()` in all of them. This is kind of a real problem with all *automatic* project management systems in IDE. That's why I prefer hand-written makefiles and use an IDE as a luxurious editor.