# Makefile duplicate symbol

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, duplicate-symbol

I want to take a brief moment that I'm aware SO is littered with these questions and I've looked at many:

- [Xcode C++ :: Duplicate Symbols for Architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436981/xcode-c-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)
- [Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 under Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)
- [ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943779/ld-1-duplicate-symbol-for-architecture-x86-64)

I'm currently building a disassembler for a school project using C++ and I'm getting blasted with duplicate symbol errors when I run my make file. I fear my issue is a little more complicated than the examples cited above. I apologize for the duplicate question but I can't figure it out after hours of searching and attempting to fix the issue and I appreciate any constructive, complete, and positive feedback anyone has.

- `g++` version 3.4.6 (yes, I know, it's old – school server)
- `make` version 3.81

Here's my makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -O0 -c

all: dasm

dasm: main.o optab.o record_tokenizer.o regex.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm *.o dasm
```

It looks like Make is able to convert all files to their respective object files but the linking into the single executable is what's failing:

```
c++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
c++    -c -o optab.o optab.cpp
c++    -c -o record_tokenizer.o record_tokenizer.cpp
c++    -c -o regex.o regex.cpp
g++ -o dasm main.o optab.o record_tokenizer.o regex.o
duplicate symbol _optab in:
    main.o
    optab.o
duplicate symbol _optab in:
    main.o
    record_tokenizer.o
duplicate symbol _HEADER_RECORD_REGEX in:
    main.o
    record_tokenizer.o
duplicate symbol _END_RECORD_REGEX in:
    main.o
    record_tokenizer.o
duplicate symbol _TEXT_RECORD_REGEX in:
    main.o
    record_tokenizer.o
duplicate symbol _MOD_RECORD_REGEX in:
    main.o
    record_tokenizer.o
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [dasm] Error 1
```

I'm definitely not a C++ expert nor am I a Makefile guru so any help is appreciated. Here are the relevant files:

**optab.h**

```
#ifndef __dasm__optab__
#define __dasm__optab__

#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<short, const char*> optab;

void init_optab();
const char* get_instruction(int n);

#endif
```

**regex.h**

```
#ifndef __dasm__regex__
#define __dasm__regex__

#include <regex.h>

bool match(const char* pattern, const char* string);

#endif
```

**record_tokenizer.h**

```
#ifndef __dasm__record_tokenizer__
#define __dasm__record_tokenizer__

#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include "regex.h"
#include "optab.h"

const char* HEADER_RECORD_REGEX = "^H[a-zA-Z|[:space:]]{6}[:digit:]{12}";
const char* END_RECORD_REGEX = "^E([:digit:]{6})?";
const char* TEXT_RECORD_REGEX = "^T[:digit:]{6}[0-1][0-E][:digit:]{,60}"; // TODO: improve on this
const char* MOD_RECORD_REGEX = "^M[:digit:]{8}";

struct Record {
    char record_type;
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    std::vector<std::string> addresses; // used for T records only
};


bool is_valid_record(const char* record, const char* pattern);
const int to_i(std::string n);
const Record tokenize_record(std::string record);

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "record_tokenizer.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int args, const char* argv[]) {
    if(args > 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: dasm sample.obj" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    tokenize_record("T0000001E^050000^032003^3F^69101791^1BA0131BC0002F200A3B2FF40F102F014F0000");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by $^ in make file? I know for $< which goes back to the beginning of stack?

Comment: No idea tbh. I found the Makefile on SO and it works. I haven't had time to look at what it actually does.

Comment: @GRC. $< and $^ are two different variables. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html.

Comment: @RSahu thank you!!! :) Learning something new every day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in `optab.h` is a problem:

```
std::map<short, const char*> optab;
```

Every `.cpp` file that includes this .h file defines `optab` as a global variable. That would result in the symbol defined multiple times.

Same errors will result from the lines:

```
const char* HEADER_RECORD_REGEX = "^H[a-zA-Z|[:space:]]{6}[:digit:]{12}";
const char* END_RECORD_REGEX = "^E([:digit:]{6})?";
const char* TEXT_RECORD_REGEX = "^T[:digit:]{6}[0-1][0-E][:digit:]{,60}";
const char* MOD_RECORD_REGEX = "^M[:digit:]{8}";
```

in `record_tokenizer.h`.

You can fix them by:

1. By making them `extern` variables and defining them in only one `.cpp` file.
2. By making them `static` variables.
3. By making them `const`. This would work for the strings but not `optab`. I imagine you will need to change its value.

   ```
   const char* const HEADER_RECORD_REGEX =  ...;
   const char* const END_RECORD_REGEX = ...;
   const char* const TEXT_RECORD_REGEX = ...;
   const char* const MOD_RECORD_REGEX = ...;
   ```

Comment: Which of the three options is best practice?

Comment: For `optab`, I would use (1). For the `***_REGEX`, I would use (3).

Comment: What exactly does `const char* const ...` do? That seems overly confusing

Comment: It means, you cannot change where the pointers point and you cannot change the values of what they point to.

Comment: Whoa, that's a trip! I didn't know you had that much control over pointers and values. So my definition in the header file would be what exactly?

Comment: `const char* HEADER_RECORDS_REGES` is actually referring to constant pointer, would `char* constant HEADER_RECORDS_REGES` which says that what is stored inside memory is constant, be enough for him? We do not care if pointer changes but content should not?

Comment: The reference to the regex string shouldn't change so it seems fitting for it to be constant

Comment: @djthoms, see [my answer to another SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27739028/434551) that talks little bit more about `const` qualifiers and pointers.

Comment: Okay, I'm just wondering because no combination seems to be working in the header and cpp file. Says I can't redefine it.

Answer (score 0):

This was the first result in google for "duplicate symbol cerr", so I think it'd help to respond here.

New gcc/clang (v10, v11) versions are by default more strict about duplicate symbols, but this behavior can be adjusted with the `-fcommon` flag

```
clang main.c -fcommon
```